# Error message: "Reference to non-existent field 'Data'

Tags: matlab

I am runnning a script and it shoots me the error message which I specified in the question. I searched online for some solutions, but it does not work for me...the script is basically loading EEG and EMG files, processing them and saving them in the end. Since I am fairly new to matlab I would greatly appreciate your help.
Below is the code plus error message:

```
Volume_name='C:\Users\Rouve\Documents\Promotion\EEG\Data_TRIAL';
EEG_RAW_DIR =[Volume_name '/EEG/'];
EEG_MAT_DIR = [Volume_name '/EEG/'];
EMG_DIR = [Volume_name '/EMG/'];
grd= sprintf(['scale,F7,F1,Fz,F4,F8,legend\n' ...
          'C5,C3,C1,Cz,C2,C4,C6\n' ...
          'CP5,CP3,CP1,CPz,CP2,CP4,CP6\n' ...
          'P5,P3,P1,O1,P2,P4,P6']);
filelist={'DENNIS_EEG_NEWSETUP_LOAD'};
file_emg={'DENNIS_EMG_Load.mat'};
[cnt, mrk_orig]= file_readBV([EEG_RAW_DIR filelist{1} '*']);
mrk=mrkodef_cmc(mrk_orig);
cnt=proc_selectChannels(cnt,'not',{'x_dir','y_dir','z_dir'});
epo=proc_segmentation(cnt,mrk,[-500 5500]);
epo_down=proc_selectEpochs(epo,[1:3:60]);
epo_up=proc_selectEpochs(epo,[2:3:60]);
mnt= mnt_setElectrodePositions(cnt.clab);
mnt= mnt_setGrid(mnt, grd);
emg=load([EMG_DIR file_emg{1}]);
mrk_emg.pos=find(diff(emg.Data{9})>0.8);
cnt_emg.clab={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'};
x=zeros(size(emg.Data{1},1),length(cnt_emg.clab));
for ch=1:length(cnt_emg.clab)
   x(:,ch)=emg.Data{ch};
end
cnt_emg.x=x;
x=zeros(round(size(cnt_emg.x,1)/6),length(cnt_emg.clab));
for ch=1:size(x,2)
   x(:,ch)=decimate(cnt_emg.x(:,ch),6);
end
cnt_emg.x=x;
mrk_emg.pos=round(mrk_emg.pos/6)';
cnt_emg.fs=500;
mrk_emg.fs=500; 
mrk_emg= convert_markers(mrk_emg);
mrk_emg.className{1}='DOWN'; %define the phases
mrk_emg.className{2}='UP';
mrk_emg.className{3}='BREAK';
mrk_emg.y=zeros(3,length(mrk_emg.time));
for i=1:3
   mrk_emg.y(i,[i:3:60])=1;
end
emg_epo=proc_segmentation(cnt_emg,mrk_emg,[-500 5500]);
file_saveMatlab([EEG_MAT_DIR filelist{1}], cnt, mrk, mnt, ...
               'channelwise',1, ...
               'format','int16', ...
               'resolution', 'auto');
file_emg_save{1}='DENNIS_PROC'; %save under new name!
file_saveMatlab([EMG_DIR  file_emg_save{1}], cnt_emg, mrk_emg,[],...         
                'channelwise',1, ...
               'format','int16', ...
               'resolution', NaN);

Reference to non-existent field 'Data'.
```

Comment: The error is crystal clear: somewhere you're referencing to a field called `Data`, which does not exist in that specific structure. It looks like the error occurs in the first `for` loop, so check what's inside of the structure `emg` and which field you should reference.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure `emg` is created by `load()`:

```
emg=load([EMG_DIR file_emg{1}]);
```

Depending on the file format you are loading, all variables saved in this file are restored as fields of structure `emg`.
The error you get means that the data file you are loading is not containing a variable with name `data`. I can imagine several reasons for this:

- You are loading the wrong file: Check filename and file contents
- The program creating the data file does not write a variable called `data`, maybe it is spelled differently in the file. Please check the program creating the data file. It should contain a statement like `save 'your_filename' 'data'`